# Why do DHCP addresses are required to be reconfigured sometimes

Tags: ip, dhcp

I was reading about DHCP somewhere and found that it provides dymically the IP addresses from the available addresses (which I probably configure in my router setup normally ranging from 192.168.1.2 to 255) but sometimes I get some dummy address like 10.x.x.x instead of proper address as 192.x.x.x. So in that case either I need to repair the address with ipconfig command or statically assign the IP address. Why do I need to do so? Is there any issue with DHCP or its issue with my router? How can I correct it??

Also same kind of issue I face when I connect my system with my android's wifi and mostly I have to put static address like 192.x.x.x.

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have another DHCP server running in your network, in addition to the one on your router, which assigns the 10.x.y.z address.

Comment: Thanks Gautam for prompt response. Not sure upon the different DHCP server, how can I check that.. also why do I need the same for network thethered by android, because that time only one device in the network probably?

Comment: Turn of your router for a check. If, after that, you get the same 10.x.y.z address every time you reboot, some DHCP server is probably assigning it to you. Maybe the DHCP server is even running on your system, accidentially? If you're on a windows system, running `ipconfig /all` from a command line shows the address of your DHCP server, among other stuff.